# Memory with incorrect voltage for motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, voltage

I just bought an Intel DP35DP motherboard. Multiple sites tell me that only 1.8V memory works.

I have 2x1GB sticks of 1.9-2.1V RAM, then another 2x1GB of 2.1V RAM.

The BIOS does detect all 4GB of memory. However it will not boot anything, including Windows Installer, Ubuntu, etc.

Could the booting issue be caused by the RAM voltage is incorrect for the motherboard?

Thanks.

Comment: Your motherboard does not support the memory you have.  You can use that expects 1.9-2.1v and only supply it 1.8v and expect it to work.

Comment: BIOS didn't give me an option to undervolt it, but I'm running it at 667MHz instead of 800 and it seems to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having incorrect power supplied to the memory can definitely cause boot issues.  I built a computer some years ago and had trouble while booting.  I could boot and start a windows install but it would always crash before finishing (at various intervals).

After troubleshooting for about a week in my spare time I found that the motherboard was supplying voltage in deficit to the ram's requirements (it was set to automatically detect and supply the voltage).  I manually set it to the memory's specifications and the problem resolved.

Just like your scenario I was able to see the memory in the BIOS, and nothing seemed problematic at first glance.  The discrepancy that I had was on the magnitude of .1-.2 volts.

Comment: Thanks, helpful anecdote! I should be able to set the voltage in the BIOS right?

Comment: Update: it's booting the Windows disc! I'm currently using 1 stick of RAM. Let's see how this goes...

Comment: Update 2: Running all 4 sticks, but this time at 667MHz. It seems to be booting the Windows disc just fine! 

Still not booting off USB, but I'm fairly certain that's another issue entirely. 

Can't believe I didn't think of this earlier.

Comment: Bios can modify voltage supplied to the memory.  It might be under advanced settings.